# Wifi autoconnect not working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

I have upgraded to 20.04. This was from 16.04, so a multi step upgrade. The required wifi network (hidden) did not show any issues during it all, but now I need to reconnect to the wifi everytime I restart. I seem to remember this being a problem in 16.04 too, think I installed a newer network manager or different network manager package.

I have tried must suggestions on various forums. I would like to try network-manager 1.28 but there are no installation information.

Did nmcli settings check and it all looks fine, ie `hidden=yes`, autoreconnect, etc. Tried this too:

```
sudo vim /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/yournetwork.nmconnection
```

and change the line to `autoconnect-priority=10`.

Thanks

Comment: Is anyone able to provide any pointers please? Thanks